# Is my script still running after having pressed Ctrl+d?

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen

I'm running a bash script in a screen, and when I recently went to check it, I pressed `Ctrl+d` instead of `Ctrl+a Ctrl+d` to detach the screen. The screen in question reacted as if I had pressed `Ctrl+l` (l as in Lucy, not the number 1), becoming blank except for the first line which is waiting for a command.

My **main question** is: Is my bash script still running unhindered in this screen?

It seems like it is when checking with `top` but I'd like to make sure it is not put on pause or something similar due to the `Ctrl+d`.
From what I understand `Ctrl+d` has sent an EOF signal which means the shell (or screen in my case) is trying to terminate. However, it doesn't seem to have terminated. Is this due to the bash script which is still running as if nothing has happened?

Comment: Was your script waiting for input from the terminal when you pressed `Ctrl+D`?

Comment: If your script not connected to a terminal (example nohup tail -f /var/log/dmesg& ) and you close that screen with Ctrl+d, the script still running. If not, your script stopped.

Comment: @Kusalananda it was not, it was iteratively running some java code.

Comment: check it with screen -ls

Comment: @K-att- The screen is marked as detached, as usual. I can attach and dettach whenever I want, but my script's prints are not shown anymore so I'm worried about the script not running anymore (even though the top command shows the java commands my script is running).

Comment: If you can deattach -> you send Ctrl+d to the script. Check the code. I think the script still running. (check it with strace ).

Comment: When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.